# Category name for restaurants NOT dressing food?

Tags: language, restaurant

Is it there a specific category name or whatever, defining restaurants that serve food without dressing, or any kind of food art or dish decoration, despite still serving good quality, tasty food, fill-me-up dishes? Not to mistake with low quality inns or cheap diners.

Comment: fast food?  ....fast casual?

Comment: maybe "rustic"?

Comment: Hi Aram - can I check something? When you say "dressing", do you mean something like non-edible decoration? As opposed to "dressing" in the sense of salad dressing?

Comment: @VinceBowdren yes, as for decoration. I'm looking if there is a standard way to categorize a place that may serve excellent cook without any decoration....served just as we would do at home.

Answer (score 3):

There are several types of restaurant that might fit your description.   I am working from a US perspective here.

1. Fast food - Quick counter or drive through service.  Mostly processed food in a restaurant that has a very casual ambiance.  Food is mostly served packaged and/or wrapped.
2. Fast casual - Often sit-down service (though can include counter service), more expensive than fast food. Can still be processed food.  Nicer ambiance, but still casual.
3. Family style restaurant - sit down service, where food is served to share on larger platters.
4. Casual dining - ambiance is still fairly casual, but nicer, less "corporate" feeling than fast casual.  Sit-down/table service and higher prices.

I guess I could also include cafes in the list...coffee shops that serve food.

None of the above place a great emphasis on the aesthetics of plating food, though each has its own aesthetic.

You could certainly find "quality" in each category, though there is definitely a range.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a concept in the United States of a ‘hole in the wall’ restaurant.  But that usually means that the restaurant is smaller, and doesn’t obviously stand out (in terms of signage and decor)

The food typically wouldn’t be pretentious, but it might still have embellishments in the dishes if that was the norm for the cuisine.

It’s the type of restaurant that you might find in a strip mall, or industrial park, or down a side alley.

It doesn’t really say anything about the quality of the food— there are high quality hole-in-the-wall restaurants, and there might be ones that aren’t so great.

It’s a category in terms of how people might describe a place… I don’t think the hospitality industry focuses on it as a category like they would ‘fast casual’ or ‘dive bar’

Answer (score 0):

Osteria In Italy.

In U.S., I would hazard a guess anyplace using the term homestyle